# Recover Virtual Disk in Azure via Snapshot

Tags: azure

i have a little problem with my azure vm. I want to restore my disk state to an older one by using an snapshot of my disk. Is this possible or do i have to create a new vm with the disk snapshot?

I didnt found any options to restore from snapshot in the online portal. is there a way with powershell?

Greetings,

N3uR0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore a data disk. But it is different for managed disk and unmanaged disk.

If you were using managed disk, then you can only create a new managed disk from the snapshot. After that you can remove your old disk from the VM, and add the new created disk to it.

[image]

If you were using unmanaged disk (page blob in storage account), then you can directly restore from a snapshot. You need to remove the data disk from the VM, and promote a snapshot. You can do this easily in [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). After that, the vhd file will be overwrote, and you just need to attach the disk to your VM again.

[image]